# Is there a way to add fields which are common to all entries in doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am quite new to Doctrine 2. I am wondering if there is an easy way / what the beast way is to include fields such as date_created, date_modified, author_id etc across all of my entities - or do I need to paste these fields into each yaml file. Would be great to specify these globally so that new fields can be easily added etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped superclass - Essentially you would create a superclass where you put your shared properties and add mappings to it, then have your actual entity classes inherit it.

See manual section [Inheritance Mapping: Mapped superclasses](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses)

Comment: Am I right that this would essentially force a switch to inline PHP annotations from yaml?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the mappings should always work with every mapping system, so you should be still able to use yaml.

Comment: yaml documentation is seriously lacking and have found several posts from people who have been unable to figure this out. Switched to annotations and snap done.